# boost::asio::write does not seem to work while boost::asio::read is outstanding

Tags: multithreading, sockets, visual-c++, tcp, boost-asio

I am using boost 1.52.0 32 bit libraries with OpenSSL 32 bit libraries with unmanaged Visual C++ 2008 for a new client I am writing to communicate with an existing server.  My test machine uses Windows 8.  I am using synchronous reads and writes.  The code is built into a DLL that is accessed from C#, but all asio calls are done on unmanaged threads created with boost::thread_group.

What I have discovered is that when a synchronous read is waiting for data, then a synchronous write taking place in another thread appears to be blocked and will not go out - at least with the way I have things coded.  So my question is - should a synchronous write be able to be completely executed while a synchronous read is waiting for data in another thread?

I have verified that I can write data out successfully when there is no pending read in another thread.  I did this by freezing the thread the read was on right before it was about to read.  The thread for writing then wrote a message out. I then thawed the read thread and it was able to successfully read the response back from the server about the message that was sent.

The following method is called by the create_thread method to handle reading messages off the wire from the server:

```
void SSLSocket::ProcessServerRequests()
{
   // This method is responsible for processing requests from a server.
   Byte *pByte;
   int ByteCount;
   size_t BytesTransferred;
   boost::system::error_code Err;
   Byte* pReqBuf;
   string s;
   stringstream ss;
   //
   try
   {
      ss << "ProcessServerRequests: Worker thread: " << Logger::NumberToString(boost::this_thread::get_id()) << " started.\n";
      Log.LogString(ss.str(), LogInfo);
      // Enable the handlers for the handshaking.
      IOService->run();
      // Wait for the handshake to be sucessfully completed.
      do
      {
         Sleep(50);
      } while (!HandShakeReady);
      //
      sClientIp = pSocket->lowest_layer().remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
      uiClientPort = pSocket->lowest_layer().remote_endpoint().port();
      ReqAlive = true;
      // If the thread that handles sending msgs to all servers has not been created yet, then create that one.
      // This thread is created just once to handle all outbound msgs to all servers.
      WorkerThreads.create_thread(boost::bind(&SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread));
      // Loop until the user quits, or an error is detected.  The read method should wait until there is something to read.
      do
      {
         pReqBuf = BufMang.GetPtr(MsgLenBytes);
         boost::asio::read(*pSocket, boost::asio::buffer(pReqBuf, MsgLenBytes), boost::asio::transfer_exactly(MsgLenBytes), Err);
         if (Err)
         {
            s = Err.message();
            if ((s.find("short r")) == string::npos)
            {
               ss.str("");
               ss << "SSLSocket::ProcessServerRequests: read(1) error = " << Err.message() << "\n.  Terminating.\n\n";
               Log.LogString(ss.str(), LogError);
            }
            Terminate();
            // Notify the client that an error has been encountered and the program needs to shut down.  TBD.
         }
         else
         {
            // Get the number of bytes in the message.
            pByte = pReqBuf;
            B2I.B.B1 = *pByte++;
            B2I.B.B2 = *pByte++;
            B2I.B.B3 = *pByte++;
            B2I.B.B4 = *pByte;
            ByteCount = B2I.IntVal;
            pReqBuf = BufMang.GetPtr(ByteCount);
            // Do a synchronous read which will hang until the entire message is read off the wire.
            BytesTransferred = boost::asio::read(*pSocket, boost::asio::buffer(pReqBuf, ByteCount), boost::asio::transfer_exactly(ByteCount), Err);
            ss.str("");
            ss << "SSLSocket::ProcessServerRequests: # bytes rcvd = " << Logger::NumberToString(BytesTransferred).c_str() << " from ";
            ss << sClientIp.c_str() << " : " << Logger::NumberToString(uiClientPort) << "\n";
            Log.LogString(ss.str(), LogDebug2);
            Log.LogBuf(pReqBuf, (int)BytesTransferred, DisplayInHex, LogDebug3);
            if ((Err) || (ByteCount != BytesTransferred))
            {
               if (Err)
               {
                  ss.str("");
                  ss << "ProcessServerRequests:read(2) error = " << Err.message() << "\n.  Terminating.\n\n";
               }
               else
               {
                  ss.str("");
                  ss << "ProcessServerRequests:read(3) error - BytesTransferred (" << Logger::NumberToString(BytesTransferred).c_str() <<
                     ") != ByteCount (" << Logger::NumberToString(ByteCount).c_str() << ").  Terminating.\n\n";
               }
               Log.LogString(ss.str(), LogError);
               Terminate();
               // Notify the client that an error has been encountered and the program needs to shut down.  TBD.
               break;
            }
            // Call the C# callback method that will handle the message.
            Log.LogString("SSLSocket::ProcessServerRequests: sending msg to the C# client.\n\n", LogDebug2);
            CallbackFunction(this, BytesTransferred, (void*)pReqBuf);
         }
      } while (ReqAlive);
      Log.LogString("SSLSocket::ProcessServerRequests: worker thread done.\n", LogInfo);
   }
   catch (std::exception& e)
   {
      stringstream ss;
      ss << "SSLSocket::ProcessServerRequests: threw an error - " << e.what() << ".\n";
      Log.LogString(ss.str(), LogError);
   }
}
```

The following method is called by the create_thread method to handle sending messages to the server:

```
void SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread()
{
   // This method handles sending msgs to the server.  It is called upon 1st time class initialization.
   //
   DWORD WaitResult;
   Log.LogString("SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread: Worker thread " + Logger::NumberToString(boost::this_thread::get_id()) + " started.\n", LogInfo);
   // Loop until the user quits, or an error of some sort is thrown.
   try
   {
      do
      {
         // If there are one or more msgs that need to be sent to a server, then send them out.
         if (SendMsgQ.Count() > 0)
         {
            Message* pMsg = SendMsgQ.Pop();
            // Byte* pBuf = pMsg->pBuf;
            const Byte* pBuf = pMsg->pBuf;
            SSLSocket* pSSL = pMsg->pSSL;
            int BytesInMsg = pMsg->BytesInMsg;
            boost::system::error_code Error;
            unsigned int BytesTransferred = boost::asio::write(*pSSL->pSocket, boost::asio::buffer(pBuf, BytesInMsg), Error);
            string s = "SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread: # bytes sent = ";
            s += Logger::NumberToString(BytesInMsg).c_str();
            s += "\n";
            Log.LogString(s, LogDebug2);
            Log.LogBuf(pBuf, BytesInMsg, DisplayInHex, LogDebug3);
            if (Error)
            {
               Log.LogString("SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread: error sending message - " + Error.message() + "\n", LogError);
            }
         }
         else
         {
            // Nothing to send, so go into a wait state.
            WaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
            if (WaitResult != 0L)
            {
               Log.LogString("SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread: WaitForSingleObject event error.  Code = " + Logger::NumberToString(GetLastError()) + ". \n", LogError);
            }
         }
      } while (ReqAlive);
      Log.LogString("SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread: Worker thread " + Logger::NumberToString(boost::this_thread::get_id()) + " done.\n", LogInfo);
   }
   catch (std::exception& e)
   {
      stringstream ss;
      ss << "SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread: threw an error - " << e.what() << ".\n";
      Log.LogString(ss.str(), LogError);
   }
}
```

So, if a synchronous write should be able to be executed while a synchronous read is pending in another thread, then can someone please tell me what my code is doing wrong.

Comment: I just discovered the reason for the problem.  After converting the calls from synchronous to asynchronous, it was still exhibiting the same problem.  It turns out that it was due to a malformed message.  The server simply does not respond to malformed messages, which I also just discovered.  So, I'm guessing that the synchronous calls were probably ok, but I am leaving it asynchronous for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asio socket is not thread-safe, so you may not access it from different threads.
Use `async_read` and `async_write` instead.